# Java method for MongoDB collection.save()

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm having a problem with MongoDB using Java when I try adding documents with customized _id field. And when I insert new document to that collection, I want to ignore the document if it's _id has already existed.

In Mongo shell, collection.save() can be used in this case but I cannot find the equivalent method to work with MongoDB java driver.

Just to add an example:

- I have a collection of documents containing websites' information
  with the URLs as _id field (which is unique)
- I want to add some more documents. In those new documents, some might be existing in the current collection. So I want to keep adding all the new documents except for the duplicate ones.
- This can be achieve by collection.save() in Mongo Shell but using [MongoDB Java Driver](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java/), I can't find the equivalent method.

Hopefully someone can share the solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In the MongoDB Java driver, you could try using the `BulkWriteOperation` object with the `initializeOrderedBulkOperation()` method of the `DBCollection` object (the one that contains your collection). This is used as follows:

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", port_number);
DB db = mongo.getDB("db_name");

ArrayList<DBObject> objectList; // Fill this list with your objects to insert
BulkWriteOperation operation = col.initializeOrderedBulkOperation();

for (int i = 0; i < objectList.size(); i++) {
    operation.insert(objectList.get(i));
}

BulkWriteResult result = operation.execute();
```

With this method, your documents will be inserted one at a time with error handling on each insert, so documents that have a duplicated id will throw an error as usual, but the operation will still continue with the rest of the documents. In the end, you can use the `getInsertedCount()` method of the `BulkWriteResult` object to know how many documents were really inserted.

This can prove to be a bit ineffective if lots of data is inserted this way, though. This is just sample code (that was found on [journaldev.com](http://www.journaldev.com/4308/mongodb-insert-example-using-mongo-shell-and-java-driver) and edited to fit your situation.). You may need to edit it so it fits your current configuration. It is also untested.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I think it doesn't really solve my question. The situation here is that I want to add a list of new documents to a current collection. One of the new documents can have the same _id (i.e. existing) in a current collection. What I want is to keep adding all the new documents and ignoring the documents with duplicate _id.

Comment: @dumblebee Oh, looks like I misunderstood your question. I edited my answer. Thanks for the precision.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the recommendation about using BulkWriteOperation. I think your usage example is using the older version of MongoDB Java Driver (2.x). But yes, I will figure it out with the latest version 3.2 :D

Answer (score 0):

I guess `save` is doing something like this.

```
fun save(doc: Document, col: MongoCollection<Document>) {

    if (doc.getObjectId("_id") != null) {
        doc.put("_id", ObjectId()) // generate a new id
    }

    col.replaceOne(Document("_id", doc.getObjectId("_id")), doc)
}
```

Maybe they removed `save` so you decide how to generate the new id.